# Xcode 7 crash symbolication with OS X Application on Mac App Store

Tags: xcode, macos, app-store-connect, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

Im trying to get crash symbolication to work on Xcode 7. My app is already on the Mac App Store and I'm getting crash reports. The problem is that they are not symbolized. When uploading to itunesconnect I did check the option to upload the DSYM files.

If you notice on the screenshot below, the first 2 lines are indeed symbolized, but they belong to one of my frameworks not the main application. The main application is giving me a 0X10093d000 symbol repeatedly.

What could be the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Update: Still don't have *all* crashes symbolicated in 7.3, but for each crash condition, we can usually page to an individual crash report which is symbolicated]

Try XCode 7.3

For reasons unknown, we can only reliably symbolicate our latest production release with XCode 7.3, even though we didn't use it to create the release.

7.3 introduced some new errors and warnings, so if you do download it, I recommend you download it from Developer Center and install in a seperate directory which does not overwrite your current XCode 7.x install.